# code completion for Firebug Command Editor

Tags: firefox, editor, firebug

Code completion for Firebug command line is great. But how can I get code completion for javascript when I open the Command Editor (multi-line editor) in Firebug?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean  by the 'command editor'? Do you mean the expanded multi-line editor?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/435987/autocompletion-in-firebug-expanded-console

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible currently in Firebug, but may land in Firebug 1.11:
http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=55

You may try this addon, but I haven't used it by myself:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug-autocompleter/